# Use content from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File

Tags: client-object-model

I have a Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File called "Algemeen.aspx" that i got from SharePoint 2010. Now i need to get the content from that file in my vb.net application. Does anyone know how this is possible?
code to find file:

```
    Dim fileAlgemeen As SP.File = Nothing
    Dim siteUrl As String = "https://portal.xx.be/sites/kdb"
    Dim ctx As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
    Dim web As Web = ctx.Web
    ctx.Load(web)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    Dim relativeUrl As String = "/sites/kdb/596/Algemeen.aspx"
    Dim file As SP.File = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl)
    ctx.Load(file)
    ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Content? You mean programmatically read the file?

Comment: Yes, on that files there is a table and I need to get the data of that table

Answer (score 0):

So you can get that file object and save that file to your disk and then read it in your vb.net application. After that you can delete  that file.

You can get the stream like:

```
//get the URL of the file you want:
    var fileRef = item["FileRef"];

    //get the file contents:
    FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(context, fileRef.ToString());

    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
          int nread = 0;
          while ((nread = fileInfo.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
          {
              memory.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
          }
          memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
          // ... here you have the contents of your file in memory, 
          // do whatever you want
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524.aspx

Comment: first, thank you for the quick answer. I am developing in vb.net, not in c#. I'll try to convert the language but what variable is "item"?

Comment: i have updated my post with the code to get the file. is fileRef the same as my relativeURL?

Comment: oke, I think it worked to convert the code. But how do I use the conent now?

Comment: You can use file read api in vb.net to read the file content.